# How to access google chart api via curl?

Tags: ajax, bash, curl, google-visualization

I want to write a bash script to generate charts based on google chart api.
[Google Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) will not available in the future.

> **Important:** The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy.

The new APIs are based on `ajax`. How to access the `ajax` based API via `curl`?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you figured out how to use the new API to download charts as images?

Comment: @temuri use `phantomjs` render as `png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is to single-quote the URL; otherwise, you'll end up with a malformed URL.

```
% curl -s 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World' > chart.png
% open chart.png

# on windows
% start chart.png
```

Comment: For zsh users, on gnome: `eog =(curl -s 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World')`